# How to rotate object in After Effects without affecting other values?

Tags: after-effects

I have a motion path of a object already defined within keyframes. Now I would like to adjust the rotation. BUT if the rotation is set, it affects also the X/Y axis of the object, that's why it completely screws up the created keyframes for position coordinates (if the object was moving upwards, I rotate it 90 degrees, it moves to the left).

So my question is, how can I rotate the object without affecting the position, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor point defines the "center" around which an object in AE moves, rotates etc. Often, when not taking care of initially setting the anchor point to the right location, rotating the object can lead to surprises. For simple position changes, you probably don't really care where the anchor point is set, once other Params get into play, this can lead to problems since effectively can look as if it affects position, in case of an object with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Hans is right - make sure the anchor point of the object you wish to rotate is positioned correctly before you make your movement keyframes.  Use the Pan Behind Tool (stupid name) to reposition the anchor point.